# Factorial -C (Linux)

Tags: c, optimization, factorial

**Please suggest me a more efficient alternative to go about this Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int k, i, t;
    int arr[100]; //Declaring an array

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        //printf("enter a value %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        fact(arr[i]);
    }

}

int fact(int num) // defining function fact(Num)
{

    int i;
    int fact1 = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        fact1 = fact1 * i;
    }

    printf("%ld\n", fact1);

}
```

Comment: Just hard-code the values! I kid you not.

Comment: Hamish is right.  A 32-bit (signed) int can only hold factorials up to 12!, and a 64-bit can only hold up to 20!.  If you're using fixints in C, a lookup table holding every possible factorial is *tiny*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factorial in C without conditionals, loops and arithmetic operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653961/factorial-in-c-without-conditionals-loops-and-arithmetic-operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For small arguments, I agree with Hamish Grubijan's comment: just tabulate the values and look 'em up at run time.  There aren't that many values for which n! is representable in a machine number, so you could tabulate them all.

The logarithm of n! is often more useful.  It will fit inside a machine number when n! itself would overflow.  See [How to compute log factorial](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/08/16/how-to-compute-log-factorial/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_formula) as an approximation for large factorials. If very large exact factorials are needed, you'll need to use bignum arithmetic. The asymptotically-best efficiency is obtained by computing n! from its prime factorization. For more algorithms, check [this](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to calculate the factorial for large numbers.

Comment: For the domain relevant to a C `int` (i.e., n<20), Stirling's approximation appears to have pretty significant error.  Why would you not just use integer arithmetic, or a lookup table?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Fast Factorial Functions](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm) website and to the [Computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Computation) section of the [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) Wikipedia article.